# Delete k-th element in a linked list (Java implementation)

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying this program but i am not able to achieve deletion. The execution is going into infinite loop. Also, i am not sure if i am forming linked list properly.

What am i missing in the following program:

```
public class SpecificNodeRemoval {
private static class Node {
    String item;
    Node next;
    Node prev;

    private Node(String item, Node next, Node prev) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k = 3;

    Node fourth = new Node("Fourth", null, null);
    Node third = new Node("Third", fourth, null);
    Node second = new Node("Second", third, null);
    Node first = new Node("First", second, null);

    second.prev = first;
    third.prev = second;
    fourth.prev = third;
    Node list = first;

    Node result = removalKthNode(list, k);

    int j = 1;
    while(result.next!=null){
        System.out.println(j+": "+result.item);
    }
}

private static Node removalKthNode(Node first, int k) {
    Node temp = first;

    for(int i=1; i < k; i++) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    temp.prev.next = temp.next;
    temp.next.prev = temp.prev;

    return temp;
}
}
```

---

THANKS A TON for answer and comments.. the working program is listed below:

```
public class SpecificNodeRemoval {
private static class Node {
    String item;
    Node next;
    Node prev;

    private Node(String item, Node next, Node prev) {
        this.item = item;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k = 3;

    Node fourth = new Node("Fourth", null, null);
    Node third = new Node("Third", fourth, null);
    Node second = new Node("Second", third, null);
    Node first = new Node("First", second, null);

    second.prev = first;
    third.prev = second;
    fourth.prev = third;
    Node list = first;

    Node result = removalKthNode(list, k);

    int j = 1;
    while(result != null){
        System.out.println(j+": "+result.item);
        result = result.next;
        j++;
    }
}

private static Node removalKthNode(Node first, int k) {
    Node temp = first;

    for(int i=1; i < k; i++) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    temp.prev.next = temp.next;
    temp.next.prev = temp.prev;

    return first;
}
}
```

The output is:
    1: First
    2: Second
    3: Fourth

Comment: When printing the values, you need to make the result 'pointer' advance. Clue: `while(result.next!=null)`

Comment: Please use debug functionality to find out which loop is going into infinite loop, this will help you.

Comment: @Buddha: i did debug, the removalKthNode is going through fine. With k=3 in this scenario, removalKthNode returns the Node Third.

Comment: the debug trace looks like this: 

result = {linked.list.SpecificNodeRemoval$Node@90}
item = {java.lang.String@91}"Third"
next = {linked.list.SpecificNodeRemoval$Node@92}
item = {java.lang.String@94}"Fourth"
next = null
prev = {linked.list.SpecificNodeRemoval$Node@77}
prev = {linked.list.SpecificNodeRemoval$Node@77}
item = {java.lang.String@89}"Second"
next = {linked.list.SpecificNodeRemoval$Node@92}
prev = {linked.list.SpecificNodeRemoval$Node@76}
item = {java.lang.String@82}"First"
next = {linked.list.SpecificNodeRemoval$Node@77}
prev = null
result.item = {java.lang.String@91}"Third"

Comment: @VijayBhore Your code is nearly working, check my answer to know why your output seems wrong.

Comment: @VijayBhore Yes removalKthNode is not the issue here.. it is the final while loop which is going to infinite loop, there may be other issues as well, but as Matthias suggested check the answer as well. There are many other improvements that can be done to your code, but I will leave it to you to work upon.

Comment: @VijayBhore congratulations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like the culprit.

```
while(result.next!=null){
    System.out.println(j+": "+result.item);
}
```

you are not progressing forward in the linked list.

I'm not exactly sure what you intended, but you may want to write as follows to avoid infinite loop...

```
while(result !=null){
    System.out.println(j+": "+result.item);
    result = result.next;
    j++;
}
```

But again if you want to print whole linked list, you should not initialise **result** with the value returned from removalKthNode function. You should start from **first**.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in your code:

1) The `removalKthNode` method should return the 1st element in the list to make your code print meaningful results (or you'll have to navigate to the 1st element again to output the remaining list.

2) The `while` loop which prints your list is wrong in two places.

a) You do not increment j, so you always put the same position for the items.

b) You do not really iterate through that list, meaning you do not reassign your variable `result`.
Try something like this:

```
 int j = 1;
 while (result != null) {
     System.out.println(j++ + ": " + result.item);
     result = result.next;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
Node result = removalKthNode(list, k);
now result = Third
```

and you have while loop as while(result.next!=null) which is always be in the Third element so it's going for infinite loop. Change the result as below

```
 while(result!=null){
        System.out.println(j+": "+result.item);
        result = result.next;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : Might help you to accompalish the Task:

```
    package com.amazon;






class Linkedlist{

    Node head;

    public Linkedlist() {
        head = null;
    }


    public  Node addNode(int data){

        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        if(head==null) head = newNode;
        else{
            Node current = head;
            while(current.next!=null){
            current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = newNode;
        }
        return newNode;
    }

}

class Node
{
    Node next;
    int data;

    Node(int d)
    {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}

public class DeleteEveryKthNodes {



    void modifyList(Node head,int k){

        Node current = head;
        Node previous = null;
        Node newHead = null;
        if(current==null)return;
        int count;
        while (current != null) {
            for (count = 1; count < k && current != null; count++) {
                previous = current;
                current = current.next; // 1--2--3--4--5
            }

            if (current != null) {
                Node temp = current;
                previous.next = current.next;
                // current = null;
                temp = null;
                current = current.next;
            }
        }

         current = head;
        while(current!=null){
            System.out.print(" "+current.data);
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {


    Linkedlist list = new Linkedlist();

    list.head = new Node(1);
    list.head.next = new Node(2);
    list.head.next.next = new Node(3);
    list.head.next.next.next = new Node(4);
    list.head.next.next.next.next = new Node(5);

    new DeleteEveryKthNodes().modifyList(list.head, 2);
    //list.head.next.next.next.next = new Node(1);



}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Java Script for circular - n=5 and k=3, it will delete every 3 element in circular list.

```
public class TEST {
    
public static int killed_position(int[] newarr,int n,int a,int p) {
    int iteration=0;
    while(true) {
        if(newarr[p-1] != 0) {
            iteration++;
            if(iteration>a-1) {
                break;
            }
        }
        p++;
        if(p>n) {
            p=1;
        }
    }
    return p;
}
public static int next_position(int[] newarr,int n,int a,int p) {
    int iteration=0;
    while(iteration<1) {
        if(newarr[p-1] != 0) {
            iteration++;
        }
        else {
            p++;
            if(p>n) {
                p=1;
            }   
        }

    }
    System.out.println("NEXT START ->" + p);
    return p;
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n=5;
        int k=3;
    
        int newarr[] = new int[n];
        int a=1;
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            newarr[i]=i+1;
        }       
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++) {
            System.out.println("START -> " + a);
            a=killed_position(newarr, n,k,a);
            newarr[a-1]=0;
            System.out.println("KILLED -> " + a);   
            a=next_position(newarr, n,k,a);
            System.out.println("---------------------");
                
        }
        System.out.println("POSITION FINAL MAN  -> " + a);
        System.out.println("POSITION FINAL MAN NAME -> " + a);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            System.out.print(newarr[i]);
        }           
    }
}
```